# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load balancer - IIS 10 Web socket error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

whose familiar here with AWS EC2 Elastic Beanstalk load balancer? I am deploying my .Net application that has SignalR using IIS 10 in EC2 and I always getting this error "WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value`.

I am using Application Load Balancer and base on this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/ Websocket is now supported in Application Load Balancer but I cannot get it to work with my app. Everytime I try to connect with SignalR it always throws that same error and my Transport Type got roll back to Long Polling method. Note that this error does not come out when running my code locally via Visual Studio or deployed in IIS.

Comment: EB uses nginx as proxy. Have you set it up to proxy wss (example [here](https://medium.com/@binyamin/node-websockets-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-elastic-load-balancer-elb-or-application-load-6a693b21415a))?

Comment: @Marcin I am using SignalR, do I need to setup this one also? I am not sure about this but it will work for node.js and not for .net app